# In a vector valued function ,what does it mean for the derivative to be zero?

Tags: derivatives, vectors

In a vector valued function ,if the derivative is zero at a point ,then the function is said to be not continuous at that point,I can't wrap my head around this idea?Could u show via **diagram** as to how a **zero derivative leads to a non differentiable function** in the context of vector valued functions.

Comment: "In a vector valued function ,if the derivative is zero at a point ,then the function is said to be not continuous at that point": it's the first time I hear of such a statement.

Comment: the statement you want us to explain is nonsense. probably you're just misquoting something you read - you should look it up and tell us **exactly** what the source says, in exactly the same words...

Comment: Sry for asking a misleading question,what I meant was ,in Thomas Calculus there is a statement stating that dr/dt is not equal to zero for a continuously turning tangent at each point ,(ie) on a smooth curve ,there are no sharp corners,why so ?,what happens when dr/dt=0,for the curve to be smooth the vector function r(t) is never 0 .Thank you for taking the time to read my question

Comment: So you're talking about a parametrized curve $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(t)$? If $\mathbf{r}'(t) = \mathbf{0}$ for some value of $t$, the curve may or may not look nice at the corresponding point, but that doesn't change the fact that $\mathbf{r}$ is both continuous and differentiable as a function of $t$. Having a nonzero derivative is a sufficient but not necessary condition for the curve to not have any corners.

Comment: Yeah but generally a zero derivative in the context of a parametric curve it is supposed to be not smooth ryt?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "In a vector valued function ,if the derivative is zero at a point ,then the function is said to be not continuous at that point". But if you are talking about functions on real euclidean spaces (ie, $f: E \subset_{\text{open}} R^n \to R^m$) then your statement is wrong. In such functions, differentiability implies continuity. Also when you say the function has zero derivative at some point, then you are explicitly assuming differentiability at that point. So "zero derivative leads to a non differentiable function" is not true either. Here is a example of a vector valued function with a extremal point, having derivative zero. [image: here is a example of a vector valued function with a extremal point, having derivative zero.]

Comment: Sry for asking a misleading question,what I meant was ,in Thomas Calculus there is a statement stating that dr/dt is not equal to zero for a continuously turning tangent at each point ,(ie) on a smooth curve ,there are no sharp corners,why so ?,what happens when dr/dt=0,for the curve to be smooth the vector function r(t) is never 0 .Thank you for taking the time to read my question

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong: "In a vector valued function ,if the derivative is zero at a point ,then the function is said to be not continuous at that point."

I have review that book, and I found it is mean: the components's derivative of a vector valued function can not equal zero at the same time. The vector valued function's components are three parametric equations. so when their derivatives equal zero at the same time, the curve they represented will be sharp and be not differentiable.